# Let be $f \in Diff(M)$. What we can say about the subgroup $span{f}< Diff(M)$? What are implications in the structure of $f$ and $M$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let be $f \in Diff(M)$. When is finite the subgroup $span\{f\}< Diff(M)$? What are implications in the structure of  $f$ and $M$?

Comment: What does $span(f)$ mean?

Comment: The smallest subgroup of $Diff(M)$ which contain $f$,   $span(f)=\{g\in Diff(M): g=f^k , k\in\mathbb{Z} \}$.

Comment: Okay, and when you talk about "homotopic class", does that mean "homotopy class" and which one?  What's the observation you're talking about?  It's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: I think you should explain in more details what you expect. For examples, what are the observations that you made? It is difficult to try to derive consequences by staring at a cyclic group.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble expressing my question. Okay, better question "When is finite the subgroup $span(f)<Diff(M)$? What are implications in the structure of $f$ and $M$?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ generates a finite group, say of order $p$, then the action of $f$ can be linearized in a neighborhood of any fixed point, turning $f$ into an orthogonal matrix with eigenvalues that are all $p$-th roots of unity. So the dynamics are ``boring''. The action of $f$ on real homology must also be by diagonalizable linear maps whose eigenvalues are $p$-th roots of unity, so again boring. If $f$ generates an infinite group, the dynamics near a fixed point can be very complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a few details to Ben McKay's answer: In the finite group case the fixed points of $f$ have a nice structure: If $f$ is not the identity, the fixed points are nowhere dense in $M$. In fact, one can see this as an easy special case of Newman's Theorem (see [1]):

Let $G \subseteq Homeo (M)$ be a finite group of homeomorphisms acting on a connected paracompact finite dimensional manifold $M$. Then the set of points with trivial isotropy subgroup is dense and open in $M$.

Of course this also follows as an easy corollary for subgroups of the diffeomorphism group from linearizing as commented on by Ben McKay. Nevertheless, Newman's theorem and actions of finite subgroups of diffeomorphisms have some interesting consequences commonly exploited by people interested in orbifolds. See for example the chapter in [2].

[1] Dress, A.: Newman’s Theorems on Transformation groups. Topology, 8:203–207, 1969

[2] Moerdijk, I. and Mrčun, J.: Introduction to Foliations and Lie Groupoids. 2003